# how can I pass parameter to javascript in flask and use it as image's src

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

I want to pass parameter to javascript and use it as image's src. But it doesn't work at all.
when I hardcoded url, it worked. And this kind of url_for  works at html too.

this is app.py

```
@app.route('/result')
def result_html():
 username = str(session['user'])
 url = 'images/'+username+'/test.jpg'
 return render_template('result.html',data = url)
```

and this is javascript function in html

```
  function checkImage(){
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "{{ url_for('static', filename=data) }}"
  img.onload = function(){
      document.getElementById("changeImg").setAttribute("src","{{ url_for('static', filename=data) }}")
      document.getElementById("changeImg").setAttribute("style","padding-top: 5%; padding-bottom : 2%")
      document.getElementById("spinner-section").setAttribute("style","display:none");
      clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

Your view:

```
@app.route('/result')
def result_html():
    demoUrl = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d4/Mickey_Mouse.png'
    return render_template('result.html', url = demoUrl)
```

Your template:

```
<img id="changeImg" >
<script>
    document.getElementById("changeImg").setAttribute("src","{{ url }}")
</script>
```